# UDATE: How to assign set of values repetitively to a timeseries?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series, forecasting, leap-year

I have datasets of hourly values for each day, according to 1) season (summer, winter and other) and 2) weekday (workday, sunday or saturday). I am trying to fill an output dataframe of 5 years such that values repeat according to the month and weekday of its DatetimeIndex:

```
input1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, ... , 24]
input2 = [4, 5, 5, 6, ... , 65]
input3 = [6, 2, 9, 4, ... , 12]
# same for input4 to input9, where lengths of all input arrays is 24

date_range = pd.date_range(start= '2020-01-01', end= '2034-12-31', freq= 'H')

df = pd.DataFrame(date_range, columns=['Date'])
df.set_index(df['Date'], inplace=True)
df.drop(['Date'], axis=1, inplace=True)

def assign_values(month, day):
    x = pd.Series()
    if (month == 6)|(month == 7)|(month == 8):
        if (day == 6):
            x.append(input1)
        elif(day == 5):
            x.append(input2)
        else:
            x.append(input3)
    elif (month < 3)|(month == 12):
        if (day == 6):
            x.append(input4)
        elif(day == 5):
            x.append(input5)
        else:
            x.append(input6)
    else:
        if (day == 6):
            x.append(input7)
        elif(day == 5):
            x.append(input8)
        else:
            x.append(input9)

df['output'] = df.apply(assign_values(df.index.month, df.index.weekday)), axis = 1)
```

I expect the output to be `df` with columns `'Date'` as index and `'output'` values assigned according to the defined function. However, I get `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` on the `df.apply`

Seems it has to do with the lengths of datasets and how to join them, but I'm really stuck here and don't know how to go further! Is there a way to iterate per day for example? Or better approach??

UPDATE: A simpler question: I tried to assign values per year first using:

```
year = pd.Series[<hourly values of one normal year>]
leap = pd.Series[<hourly values of one leap year>]

for i in range(2026, 2051):
 if i % 4 == 0:
  df[str(i)]['output'] = leap.values
 else:
  df[str(i)]['output'] = year.values
```

There are no errors raised, but the values are not added to `df.output`

Comment: where do you get an error?

Comment: on the `df.apply` module, and an update on the error: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: Do you have the same error when taking out the `pd.DatetimeIndex()` ?

Comment: If I take out the `pd.DatetimeIndex()` it returns `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'month'`